# Netlogo freezes when I inspect a turtle

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to build a very simple mode that has only 10 turtles. All of them are connected to one parameter with directed links. When I try to inspect this turtle, Netlogo freezes which forces me to restart the model. Inspection is working fine with other turtle. Is there a solution for this please?

Comment: I have never seen this. Do you try and inspect using a command like `inspect turtle 0` or do you use the mouse/pointer and the pop up menu?

Comment: You may need to report this to https://github.com/scala/bug/issues

Comment: I'm having the same problem, although my model is quite complicated.

Comment: @bischrob I have found that the problem is having a parameter that takes too long to be calculated. As you know, parameters appear in the inspection screen, so they need to be calculated before appearing.

Comment: @saedahmad that's true, but it's freezing for several minutes.